# How to represent a method inside a method in a UML Class diagram

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram

I am trying to create a UML class diagram for one of my classes and am unsure how to represent a certain element of the class. One of the methods within my class has a method within it. How would I represent this in the diagram?

```
public void start(){
    ...
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In `java` you can't have method inside method.

What you have is method inside anonymous class inside method.

So you have to put that anonymous class in your diagram and add method to it.

PS: Some languages allow method inside methods. In that case you do not add them to class diagram because those inner method is implementation details.

Comment: When you can't have methods inside methods, then the code fragment in the OP is incorrect, is it?

Comment: It may be correct if you replace `...` to right code. Like `void start() { new Runnable(){ public void run(){}};}`